# Draw lines that surround the circles that found from hough transform(emgu cv)

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am using visual Studio Ultimate 2010 & Emgu cv 3.0.0.2157.
I Compiled Emgu cv "Shape Detection" example witch found below:
[Shape Detection Example](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_(Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line)_Detection_in_CSharp)
I want draw lines that surround founded circle in image.(like a rectangle surround a circle).
regards

Answer (score 0):

I write this code and it is what I want:

```
int aaa = (int)circle.Center.X;
            int bbb = (int)circle.Center.Y;
            Point start = new Point(aaa - (int)circle.Radius, bbb - (int)circle.Radius);
            Point second = new Point(aaa - (int)circle.Radius, bbb + (int)circle.Radius);
            LineSegment2D line5 = new LineSegment2D(start, second);
            CvInvoke.Line(circleImage, start, second, new Bgr(Color.Green).MCvScalar, 2);
```

Regards